# Get a value in querytset on basis of foregin key value django

Tags: django

I have a queryset in which I am getting all products like this

```
products=Products.objects.all()
```

**and other table of wishlist**

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isFavourite=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer ,on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True)
```

Now I have want to get value of wishlist in every product in form of True or False. like  In product 1 customer 1 have True or False value of that product or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `related_name` to customer field in Wishlist like this:

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isFavourite=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer ,on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True, related_name="wishlists")
```

you can add to your template context something like this:

```
context = {
    "products": Product.objects.all(),
    "favourites_products_ids": list(customer.wishlist.filter(isFavourite=True).values_list("product__id", flat=True))
}
```

Then in the template you can do something like this:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% if product.id in favourites_products_ids %}
        is favourite
    {% else %}
        is not favourite
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

i assumed that you are showing this in a django template or if you are using DRF you can do the same in the serializer.

Comment: thanks for answer . No I want if a user like x come every product which is showing on website there should be a calculated variable isFavourite=True or False in my queryset against every product in product all queryset on basis of which customer is login.

Comment: @gamer i updated the answer, maybe this gonne help you.